# Provide default values to config macros

Tags: c, macros, header-files, c-preprocessor

I use a few macros (`#define`) as compile-time config constants.

```
#define WS_T_1H  700
#define WS_T_1L  150
#define WS_T_0H  150
#define WS_T_0L  700
#define WS_LATCH_NS 6000
```

Those are in my header file.

However, I want to allow the user to override them when they include it - so far I have this, but it's very verbose and ugly.

```
#ifndef WS_T_1H
#define WS_T_1H  700
#endif

#ifndef WS_T_1L
#define WS_T_1L  150
#endif

#ifndef WS_T_0H
#define WS_T_0H  150
#endif

#ifndef WS_T_0L
#define WS_T_0L  700
#endif

#ifndef WS_LATCH_NS
#define WS_LATCH_NS 6000
#endif
```

I'm wondering if it's the right way? Is this a "best practice"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that's the only right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard idiom for C.  If you don't like writing such code (many people don't) you can learn autoconf, which provides an alternative syntax for defining macro defaults.  Then autoconf will write the idiomatic C code for you.